# How to query objects with the longest time period?

Tags: mongodb, date

I'm looking for a query that would return the objects with the longest time period.

So the each entry in the collection has attributes of `startDate` and `finishDate` for example:

```
id: 1  startDate: 2019-01-22 23:23:47  finishDate: 2019-01-22 20:58:47 
id: 2  startDate: 2019-01-22 23:12:47  finishDate: 2019-01-22 11:58:47
id: 3  startDate: 2019-01-22 23:23:47  finishDate: 2019-01-22 13:58:47
```

How do I find 2 items with the longest time period difference between `endDate` and `startDate`?

Comment: Calculate the difference when storing the record, then store that value in another field in the entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dates are `String`s, and since they are quite nicely formatted, you can convert them to `Date` objects using `Mongo 4.0`'s [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) converter. (with earlier versions you can use [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/))

Once you have dates, you can obtain their difference with [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/index.html) which provides the number of milliseconds between the two dates.

We can thus add this field to each document with [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/index.html) (or [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/index.html) starting `Mongo 4.2`) and thus sort all documents by decreasing order on this new `period` field via the [`$sort`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sort/index.html) operator.

Finally, to only keep the two documents with the longest periods, you can apply a [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/index.html) stage:

```
// { id: 1, startDate: "2019-01-22 20:58:47", finishDate: "2019-01-22 23:23:47" }
// { id: 2, startDate: "2019-01-22 11:58:47", finishDate: "2019-01-22 23:12:47" }
// { id: 3, startDate: "2019-01-22 13:58:47", finishDate: "2019-01-22 23:23:47" }
db.collection.aggregate([
  { $addFields: {
      period: { $subtract: [ { $toDate: "$finishDate" }, { $toDate: "$startDate" } ] }
  } },
  { $sort: { period: -1 } },
  { $limit: 2 }
])
// { id: 2, period: NumberLong(40440000), startDate: "2019-01-22 11:58:47", finishDate: "2019-01-22 23:12:47" }
// { id: 3, period: NumberLong(33900000), startDate: "2019-01-22 13:58:47", finishDate: "2019-01-22 23:23:47" }
```

Comment: Great Answer! :)